# ios convert int to NSObject

Tags: ios, casting, int, nsobject

in my function I have a parameter of NSObject* type, to allow to pass NSString, NSDate, etc.. and intenally do something...
I need to pass also a value of type int..
how can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `NSNumber` class (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and initialize it with the `numberWithInt` method.

Answer (score 3):

@Itamar's answer is sufficient, but I'm just simplifying it.

Try this,

```
NSNumber *your_object = [NSNumber numberWithInt:int_value];
```

So now int_value is converted into object.